# $f'(x) > 0$, does that imply the limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$ is $\infty$?

Tags: limits

Given the following situation: $f'(x) > 0$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I am trying to find if there is a flaw in my understanding of the properties of this situation. I assert that in the situation where $x$ approaches $\infty$ that the limit is not always $\infty$.

If I were for example to construction a piecewise function like:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{|x|}{|x|+ 1} & x\geq 0 \\
\frac{-|x|}{|x|+ 1} & x\lt 0
\end{cases}
$$

We can see that the limit is 1. Am I correct in my assertion and understanding?

Comment: $f(x)=-e^{-x}$ works too.

Comment: what about $1- \frac1x?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, another example would be $f(x) = \arctan(x)$. 
The derivative is stricly positive and the function is bounded.

Some more details: The derivative is $f'(x) = \frac {1}{1+x^2}\leq1$, but $ |f(x)| < \frac {\pi}{2}$.

We can further investigate a somewhat reverse scenario, take a function $g(x)$ such that $g'(x) \xrightarrow {x \rightarrow \infty} 0$.
Does that mean the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} g(x) \in \mathbb R$?
No. Take, for example $g(x) = \log(x)$

I hope that gives you some intuition.

Comment: You probably mean $0 < \frac{1}{1+x^2} = f'(x) \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the limit as $x \to \infty$, then $-1/x$ works.